# command 'at now' via PHP

Tags: php, linux, bash, apache, centos

I'm trying to run `at` command via PHP

```
<?php
shell_exec("echo \"php /tmp/skript.php `whoami`\" | at now");
echo shell_exec("atq 2>&1");
```

output:

> 247    2016-07-14 11:30 = apache

But the command `at` is not executed and after this, and the time disappear from the queue.

---

I'm running Cent OS on my production server. (SELinux is disabled)

When I'm running this on my personal computer with Debian, everything works well. (SELinux disabled here too)

---

The permissions are OK:

```
bash-4.1$ ls -l /tmp/skript.php
```

> -rwxrwxrwx 1 admin admin 741 13. čec 08.16 /tmp/skript.php

---

When I execute the shell as *apache*

```
me@PC:~$ sudo -u apache /bin/bash
bash-4.1$ echo "php /tmp/skript.php `whoami`" | at now
```

script **will be executed** as *apache*

---

When I do this:

```
me@PC:~$ sudo usermod -s /bin/bash tom
```

everything works, but this is BAD and not the way I would like to do. This is not an answer/solution for me.

My Debian has *apache* as shell */bin/nologin* too and it's working. Also `at.deny` is empty and `at.allow` doesn't exist.

Can somebody answer this tricky question?